# Thank you Susi Lehtola, for your contributions! You are the first to answer 50 questions :)

Tags: discussion, thanks, congratulations, community, celebration

Although we have [achieved many milestones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109902/milestones) already, some of them deserve more public recognition, celebration or congratulation. I am pleased to announce that Susi has reached 50+ answers, which I think deserves our thanks, because without these contributions our site would be nowhere near as successful as it is today:

[image]

All of the top 10 most active Beta users ought to be applauded and thanked for their role in helping build and shape this community:

[image]

Thank you everyone, and let's continue to grow the community, while making contributions to the knowledge, education, and outreach in our field!

Comment: +10 Hear! hear!